# In a database view written in sql, will updating values in the view impact those values in the original table?

Tags: sql, view

In a database view written in sql, will updating values in the view impact those values in the original table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? All of them use "*SQL*" to write views.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

- the view is updatable, which is a fairly big assumption, and
- you have sufficient privileges,

then yes, changing values in the view changes the values in the underlying base tables.

It's probably possible to create an updatable view that throws away changes, but I've never seen that done.

In many cases, you have to write procedural code to make a view updatable. The procedural code is *probably* not SQL. Instead, the procedural code is in a language the dbms supports for stored procedures and triggers. For example, in PostgreSQL, you'd probably write the procedural code in plpgsql. (PostgreSQL supports other languages, but plpgsql is the most common.)

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is flawed.  There *are no values* in a view.  There are only the underlying values in tables.  The view simply arranges those values (possibly aggregating or formatting them in various ways) but the contents of the view are transitory and not stored.

Any system that allows you to update a value in a view is directly manipulating the underlying table.

There exist in some database management systems there exist something called *materialized views* in which the view is essentially pre-computed when the underlying tables are updated and the contents are technically stored in the database.  This is purely a performance optimization and it does not mean that you are allowed to update the value in the view separately from the real, stored table value.

Comment: "*it does not mean that you are allowed to update the value in the view separately from the real, stored table value*" - in Oracle you can actually do that (it's used for multi-master replication)

Comment: Can't find any place to read about that, can you point me to a link (would like to know more)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF54174  and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm#REPLN305